# visitor numbers / the number of visitors

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> (1) Visitor **numbers** increase in the summer. ([source](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/numbers))
>
> (2) The number of visitors increases in the summer.

Sentence (1) is incomprehensible to me, and I would say sentence (2).

What logic is behind the use of plural **numbers**?

Comment: December 1250; January 800; July 3500, August 4,600. The summer numbers are bigger.

Comment: Related (but not well answered) [The number of vs The numbers of](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/253745/the-number-of-vs-the-numbers-of) and [Number(s) of + . . . OR . . . + number(s)?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/184385/numbers-of-or-numbers)

Comment: This kind of thing can be googled.

Comment: I googled, but I couldn't find an answer, hence this thread. Is ELL Stack Exchange a site for advanced learners of English? I am not an advanced learner of English.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple,  "Visitor numbers" means the same as "Number of visitors".
It doesn't mean that you get more numbers in summer.  It just means you get more visitors in summer.

Don't try to analyse it more than that. The logic probably comes from the notion of "numbers" as being "the numbers recorded in a database, or in a record book. And these tend to be higher in summer. So you might hear people talking about "Getting good numbers" meaning that they are getting good results in whatever they are recording (sales, production, quality etc).

Comment: Thank you, James. Does *Bee numbers are decreasing in Japan* sound natural in formal writing?

Comment: I just watched [*This Is 40* (2012)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1758830/) last night, where one of the central characters runs a record label in terminal decline. He bets the farm on funding one last record that he hopes might sell well and save the business. Amusingly, the "last ditch" artist is Graham Parker, who I used to like back in the day ("Graham Parker and the Rumour"). Parker plays a couple of good songs (good to old fogeys like me, I mean - not likely to be commercially successful). Two or three times the main guy says "numbers are coming in", but we know they'll be *low* numbers!

Comment: I had to admire Parker for playing himself in a movie partly predicated on the idea that he's not likely to produce another hit record. But checking just now, I see [his mini-bio on IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1470645/bio/?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm) actually says *Parker's concerts are very popular, but his record sales have had more limited success.*

Comment: "Bee numbers" - eg [here](https://www.science.org/content/article/bee-butterfly-numbers-are-falling-even-undisturbed-forests)  But I think the "the bee population has declined/decreased" sounds a little more formal.